# How to Boot from CD ROM on ASUS X551M

Tags: boot, compact-disc

I have an ASUS X551M that I am trying to boot from the CD ROM. When I go to the boot menu the screen says:

Boot Option #1   Windows Boot Manager

Add New Boot Option
Delete Boot Option

There is no option to boot from anywhere else! Please help!

Answer (score 15):

To get the ASUS X55U to boot first from the DVD drive do the following:

1. Press “ESC” or “F2” to enter the BIOS setup
2. Under the “Security” tab, choose "Secure Boot Menu," disable “Secure Boot Control”
3. Under the “Boot” tab, enable “Launch CSM”
4. Save the changes and exit
5. Press “ESC” or “F2” to enter the BIOS setup again
6. Under the “Boot” tab, the DVD drive and available flash drives will
   appear. Set the DVD drive as the first boot option. (You might need to have a bootable disk in the drive in order for it to appear as a choice)
7. Save the changes and exit

Now the X55U will first attempt to boot from the DVD drive. Moreover, if the boot menu is accessed, the DVD drive, hard drive, and USB flash drives (if detected), will appear as boot options.

see http://www.canbike.ca/information-technology/2013/03/12/asus-uefi-boot-from-cd-dvd-x55u.html for visual examples showing how to do this.

Comment: Under the boot tab there isn't the option "Launch CSM"

Comment: How about step 3, does that work?   That is the actual thing you need to change is the secure boot option.   Not too sure what Launch CSM is actually referring to.

Comment: This is correct but you must first ensure you have the latest BIOS from ASUS. I didn't have the LAUNCH CSM option until I updated the BIOS and that was the only way it will work.

Comment: ESC nor F2 seem to work for the ASUS X551M.  Any other possible keys?  Does Fn need to be held down?

Comment: After applying updates for windows, Restart becomes an option and Del launches BIOS directly while Escape launches boot menu.  Thanks!  +1

Comment: `You might need to have a bootable disk in the drive in order for it to appear as a choice` this sentence helped me. Our DVD was not bootable, that was the problem. Replaced the DVD with a bootable one and problem got solved.

Comment: You might have an option to choose what to boot in the set up menu.  Mine had a "override" option.

Comment: This also works for an Asus X551C, but between steps 2 and 3 you need to reboot, because otherwise "Launch CSM" cannot be enabled. It becomes available after said reboot.